# Setting Date Parameters in SQL string for the BETWEEN keyword. Specifically Oracle OleDb provider

Tags: c#, sql, oracle11g, between, oledbcommand

I am working in C# using oraOleDb.oracle provider to query from a table. I have a question regarding using '?' in my SQL string where a BETWEEN keyword is used. My problem is how do I add 2 parameters for a single field?

```
        string strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT PRODUCT_LINE, MODEL_YEAR, ORDER_DATE "
                    + "FROM ORDER_BANK "
                    + "WHERE ((PRODUCT_LINE = ?) AND (MODEL_YEAR = ?) AND (ORDER_DATE BETWEEN ? AND ?))";

        Command = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, Connection);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("PRODUCT_LINE", strprodline);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("MODEL_YEAR", strModelYear);
        // ??? WHAT DO I DO HERE FOR "(ORDER_DATE BETWEEN ? AND ?)"
```

Comment: Add 2 more parameters. Also BETWEEN is inclusive and really tricky to use with dates. You might want to stick with >= and <.

Comment: Thanks for response. How would I add 2 more parameters to a single field ORDER_DATE? Using >= and <.

Comment: Managed to get it working with ..... Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", strprodline); Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", strModelYear); Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", strStartDate); Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", strEndDate);  in the order that they appear in the WHERE clause

Answer (score 1):

Why do you don't do this simpler, like bulding the sql string directly. for example:

```
var sql = $"select * from table where table.date1 between '{date1.toShortDateString()}' and {date2.toShortDateString()} and model_year = '{strModelYear}' and ....;";
Command = new OleDbCommand(sql, Connection);
```

C# >= 6.0 allows you to use "$" before a string and that means that all between { and } will executable code.

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48648186/query-from-c-sharp-code-outputting-differently-from-sql-server-query] wich shows how you can use named parameter like "@date1" and "@date2" inside the sql string and later put the value for them.