# Query from C# code outputting differently from SQL Server query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, output

Working with:

- ASP.Net web-forms application
- C# code not vb.net
- SQL Server with hard coded test data

**Note**: this issue doesn't cause any errors or cause any disruption in the code, however it outputs differently from expected.

What I am trying to do is populate a Gridview using code behind file, which can be updated by the user on button click.

Code to populate:

```
protected void PopulateReport()
{
    // create connection  and add commands
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
    con.Open();

    if(RP_SelectEmp.Text == "ALL")
    {
         string query1 = "SELECT RequestID, empName, RequestType, RequestDesc, RequestStartDate FROM TOR WHERE (RequestStartDate > @StartDate)" +
                                    " AND (RequestEndDate < @EndDate) AND (granted = @State)";

         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query1, con);

         // needed conversions
         DateTime startD = Convert.ToDateTime(RP_FromDateSelect.Text);
         DateTime endD = Convert.ToDateTime(RP_EndDateSelect.Text);
         Boolean state = Convert.ToBoolean("True");

         // needed parameters
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", state);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", startD);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", endD);

         // import into gridview
         using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
         {
             if (reader.Read())
             {
                 GridView1.DataSource = reader;
                 GridView1.DataBind();
             }
             else
             {
                 RP_ErroField.Text = "failed to bind data (reader not read) check C# code";
             }
         }

         con.Close();
    }
}
```

This compiles and returns no errors but outputs:

[image: on Run Page output (pic)]

The database table includes all the correct data types and column names:

[image: The Table's show data view]

What I have tried:

1. creating a static data Source and passing in the same select string from the above code (this returns the hard coded event, with the same exact input from the fields seen in the picture) - which tells me the query isn't wrong [AddingDataSource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4PlF.png),[InputingData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM1dv.png),[Correct event Grabbed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDDio.png)
2. I have tried changing the conversions in the code, `DateTime.Parse` and `Convert.ToDateTime` had the same result. Same can be said for bool and Boolean
3. I have tried the each where clause separately and got the same no data to display result.
4. I have debugged this if statement for 2 hrs and all the variable data is doing exactly what it should (going to the if, converting, setting the values, running the reader, and databinding)

I don't know what else to try. I would like help on an action plan to fix this; maybe I am missing something, or my approach is wrong/outdated.

Comment: Remove parameters one at a time from your WHERE clause until the data reappears.  That will tell you which parameter is failing the query (it's probably the "state" one).

Comment: What is the data type of `granted` in the database? What is the entire query1 value when the query is run?

Comment: Forgot to mention: button click only contains PopulateReport(); for those who will ask

Comment: @RobertHarvey Hi Robert, thanks for the reply but i have already tried and both the datetimes and the boolean seem to cause the same issue.

Comment: @JacobH  hi Jacob. the value for the query1 run can be seen in the correct event grabbed list

Comment: I disagree with your assessment that hard coding the values in the query means that your current code "isn't wrong". There's no way you can guarantee the query generated by this code is identical to some other code you wrote.

Comment: Ok I had to log on phone to look at pictures. One thing I noticed is you are storing time values for these dates, can you give an example of the data you would be passing (preferably the entire query1...) for the 3 parameters? Also, the pictures do not show the data types. If granted is text it probably won't evaluate the boolean comparisons properly.

Comment: @JacobH  That is true however i have provide the image from the datasource configuration and the select command i wrote was just a copy paste from the code. so we can conclude that the 2 strings are correct

Comment: @JacobH the data is is text from a textbox converted to datetime                        so RP_FromDateSelect.Text outputs "2018-2-1" then is converted into DateTime {2/1/2018 12:00:00 AM} (note the column data type is also Datetime)

Comment: @JacobH the data Type for the boolean is set to bit

Comment: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: @SeanLange read though the article and made the needed changes to my code but i am still getting the same issue.

Comment: You have to fill data into datatable instead of bind directly with gridview, and that also easy to debug

Comment: The article was not intended as a solution to the problem, I should have mentioned that. It is intended to help you avoid other issues using AddWithValue.

Comment: @SeanLange I wasn't aware AddWithValue had such a data parsing issue. Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: Try commenting out the `reader.Read()`.  If you're binding a `DataReader` to a data source like this, you don't need to have started reading the reader first.  The `Read()` might even be skipping the first (and apparently only) record.

Comment: @TonyDong hi Tony you helped me realize something i was missing. the fill itself didn't work but a dataTable.Load(reader) worked instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really just a debugging exercise.

First, double-check that you haven't simply named the two date-picker controls backwards! That happens a lot.

Next: go to SSMS, and take your existing query:

```
SELECT RequestID, empName, RequestType, RequestDesc, RequestStartDate
FROM TOR 
WHERE (RequestStartDate > @StartDate)
AND (RequestEndDate < @EndDate) AND (granted = @State)
```

Now; we know that you've used `Convert.ToDateTime` to parse the dates, and that's great. You might want to check the cultures that it is parsing to what you *expect* it to parse to (is 1/2/2018 the first of Feb? or the 2nd of Jan?), and when you're 100% sure what the *actual date* of `startD` and `endD` are, prepend these to your query using an unambiguous format (just to help us debug); do the same thing with `state`; for example:

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '01 Jan 2018';
DECLARE @EndDate datetime = '03 Jan 2018';
DECLARE @State bit = 1;
```

or are they?

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '01 Jan 2018';
DECLARE @EndDate datetime = '01 March 2018';
DECLARE @State bit = 1;
```

So now we have spoofed the parameters and you have the exact same query: run it. 99% of the time, doing this will show you what is wrong with the query. I would *expect* that the query in SSMS now behaves like the query from your application does. So; now go fix it!

Comment: This is a great answer, I have tried your suggestion but that doesn't help the issue. From direct SQL query event has run properly and returned the correct data. the query proved successful when run through a data source as well as this test you suggested.  the issue lies when i try this test from the code behind file, when run without granted nothing shows up, as if data is grabbed but not rendered, when i run with bool no data is grabbed. Render is another issue but this issue seems to be passing a value to match with bit from c# code any suggestions?

Comment: Your comment had me checking the little things. Thanks to that and an article on AddWithValue shared by Sean Lange i was able to get the right data to the table. once i was no longer getting the "no data to display" message i knew i was getting the data but i was missing something on the render, and sure enough I forgot to switch AutoGenerateColumns to true on the gridview properties.